# Abbreviation for bachelor's degree with minor

Tags: professionalism, email, education, degree

When describing the degree one has obtained or is pursuing (for example in an email signature), is there a way to include information about a minor in a cleanly abbreviated manner?

For example, someone who is working towards a degree in Mechanical Engineering would list their degree as `BSME`.  If they were also pursuing a minor in Electrical Engineering, how would one go about listing this?

Furthermore, in the situation where one is still pursuing the degree and sending emails primarily to university faculty and potential employers, is it even commonplace or helpful to include this information about pursuing a minor in the signature?

**Edit:** Here's my current signature format for reference.  Currently I have it along with the school name and graduating year, not directly after my name.

```
--
First Name Last Name
University of XYZ ’21 BSME
email | (xxx) xxx - xxxx
```

Comment: You want to add a degree you don't have to your email signature?  Leave it out. 
 Maybe include the "'21 ME" part but that's all.  In business, whenever I see somebody that feels compelled to list their education with their signature, I always think that is all they have going for them.  If they were worth anything, they would leave it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When describing the degree one has obtained or is pursuing (for example in an email signature), is there a way to include information about a minor in a cleanly abbreviated manner?

B.S in Mechanical Engineering with minor in Electrical Engineering.

> is there a way to include information about a minor in a cleanly abbreviated manner?

There isn’t a universal abbreviation for a minor degree.

> Furthermore, in the situation where one is still pursuing the degree and sending emails primarily to university faculty and potential employers, is it even commonplace or helpful to include this information about pursuing a minor in the signature?

I don’t typically think listing unfinished degrees is worth while.  I would only list what degrees I was pursuing on a resume.

Comment: "unfinished degree" is a "degree you pursuing"

Comment: @aaaaaa - There are people who don't complete programs but still list the program on their resume.

Comment: @aaaaaa There's also "degree you tried to pursue but were unable to complete". For instance, you might try to do a Post-Graduate Diploma of Education (Secondary), only to discover on your practicums that you aren't suited for that line of work.

Answer (score 2):

You posted your signature for reference in an edit to the question, and it looked like this:

```
 --
 First Name Last Name
 University of XYZ ’21 BSME
 email | (xxx) xxx - xxxx
```

When I read signatures in this format, I naturally assume that the name of an organization in the second line would be the organization that the author is *employed by*, not where they went to school. So, I think it’s confusing.

Plus, part of the point of an email signature is to make it easy for recipients to identify and contact you. If I pick up my phone and dial University of XYZ’s main office telephone number and ask to speak to the name in the signature, is the receptionist there going to be able to transfer my call to you? I’m guessing not.

I would not list anything about your education in your signature. If you haven’t completed a degree yet but are looking for jobs where it is relevant that you are studying something (e.g. internships?), then you can explain that in your cover letter, resume, or CV. Your email signature should contain information that can be used to identify and contact you, e.g. your name, company, phone number, mailing address, etc.

Comment: good point. Signature is about place of work

Answer (score 1):

> sending emails primarily to university faculty [...], is it even commonplace or helpful to include this **information about pursuing a minor in the signature**?

Signature is the last bit of information anybody going to notice. People do often add "Joan Smith, PhD" or "John Smithsonian, MD" to their signature, but I have never seen "Dardeshna Secondname, BS, Physics" and especially not "Dardeshna Secondname, BS, Physics, minor in Music".

In academia, focus on writing good cover letter that clearly explains what you want from the person and why they should care to read your CV. Then, in CV, list your degrees, and degrees in progress:

```
Academic University (USA) BS Physics, minor in Music ..... 2016-today
```

or

```
College of Sciences (UK) BS Physics ..................... 2016-today
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on focusing on the CV.  See my edited post, thinking more for the second line of a signature where you might also list your university and graduating year.

Comment: @dardeshna thanks for the edit, it clears things up. As I wrote, I doubt signature will be noticed by anyone. In my email client (GMail) I think signature is never even shown by default